# Behavior of array as index in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

Index of array may be array by itself (tested in Chrome):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
index = [1]
a[index] // returns 2
```

Is there any official documentation of this behavior?

Comment: but what if `index = ['hello world']` or `[1,2]`?

Comment: The subscript operator converts its argument to a string, and the `.toString()` of an array is `.join()`

Comment: `a[1]` is `a['1']` is `a[['1'].join(',')]` is `a[String(['1'])]` is `a[['1']]` is `a[[1]]`.

Comment: Try this. What result do you get? `var a = [1, 2, 3]
var index = [1, 2]
console.log(a[index]);`

Comment: This is one of the bad parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any official documentation of this behavior?

[`12.3.2.1Runtime Semantics: Evaluation`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-property-accessors-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

defines the following 3 steps

3 Let `propertyNameReference` be the result of evaluating `Expression`.
4 Let `propertyNameValue` be ? `GetValue(propertyNameReference)`.
6 Let `propertyKey` be ? `ToPropertyKey(propertyNameValue)`.

Then [`7.1.14ToPropertyKey ( argument )`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-topropertykey) is defined as

1. Let `key` be ? `ToPrimitive(argument, hint String)`.
2. If `Type(key)` is `Symbol`, then
   a. Return `key`.
3. Return ! `ToString(key)`.

Which effectively means, that unless the expression returns a `Symbol` - it (the key) would be converted to a string.

Answer (score 3):

As @Ryan and @4castle mentioned, javascript convert `key`(inside []) to string using `[].join(',')`.
You can test it in this snippet.

```js
var abc = {
  "1,2": "ddd"
  };
 console.log(abc[[1,2]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`a[index]` will do a toString on the index, and since index is an array, its to string is `index.join()` making the output `a['1']`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors